# Issue with installing psycopg2-binary in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to install psycopg2-binary on a virtual machine using Jenkins pipeline. Due to no network connectivity I have to do it via:

```
pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install -r ${WORKSPACE}\\requirements.txt --no-index --find-links=${python_packages_dir}
```

Unfortunately, even though I'm using compiled version it still returns error, as if it was trying to build the package:

```
12:20:34      Error: pg_config executable not found.
12:20:34      
12:20:34      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
12:20:34      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
12:20:34      option:
12:20:34      
12:20:34          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
12:20:34      
12:20:34      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
12:20:34      
12:20:34      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
12:20:34      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
12:20:34      
12:20:34      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
12:20:34      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
12:20:34      
12:20:34      ----------------------------------------
12:20:34  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Not sure how to proceed from here, any help?